# I am trying to work on the get method of the Linked List in Python where the user puts an index and it gives the data that is in that index

Tags: python, linked-list, indexof

```
class node(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.data = None #Contains data 
        self.next = None #Contains the reference to the next node 
        self.position = 0

    def get_data(self):

        return self.data

    def get_next(self):

        return self.next_node

    def set_next(self, new_next):

        self.next_node = new_next 

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):

        self.head = None

    def add_node(self,data): 

        new_node = node() #Creates a new node 
        new_node.data = data 
        new_node.next = self.head #Referencing 
        self.head = new_node #Set the next code as the current node 

    def get(self,index):

        current = self.head
        while current:
            if current.position == index:
                print current.data
                break
            else:
                current = current.next
            print("None")
```

So I can't figure out how to make the get function work properly. It just returns 0 no matter what index I put it.

Comment: You are referencing to `next_node`, but those are no actual properties. Is this your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

You never actually set the `position` property on your node. I see no reason to store a position, though, you can just keep an index while iterating over the list.

For example:

```
def get(self, index):
    current = self.head
    while current and index >= 0:
        if index == 0:
            return current.data
        current = current.next
        index -= 1
```

Comment: I tried that but then it says: <__main__.Node object at 0x029B1A30>